# node.js perf_hooks time output

Tags: javascript, node.js, performance

I was reading up on the [Performance Hooks](https://nodejs.org/api/perf_hooks.html) now available in node and when I try to use one of their timing outputs like `performanceEntry.duration`, it says the output is in milliseconds. When I console.log out their code examples on that page like `console.log(items.getEntries()[0].duration)`, the time output looks like this:

```
0.306935 (start mark)
3.656406 (end mark)
```

then when i use their `startTime` output `items.getEntries()[0].startTime`, I get time like this:

```
5346.841204
```

All time output on that documentation page says it is in milliseconds. However, I've never seen milliseconds with decimal places in it before. Are these actually seconds being output instead? If so, what would `5346.841204` correlate to exactly?

Comment: Wouldn't it just mean 5.346 seconds (plus .841 204 additional milliseconds)? The performance timer is at a nanosecond precision.